# Show error marker for external resource

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, markers

I have written an eclipse editor that performs syntax checking and if it finds an error, it will display it in the editor.

Currently I am doing this by creating a marker in the respective `IResource` and that is working well until the user uses the `File -> Open File...` option in order to open a non-project file with that editor.

The problem is that the `EditorInput` is no longer an `IFileEditorInput` (it's a `FileStoreEditorInput`)  that allowed me to retrieve the connected `IResource` via `getFile()` (on which I can add the marker via `createMarker()`). In fact the core problem is that the opned file isn't an `IResource` at all (at least that is what I'm guessing as it is not in the eclipse workspace).

Is there another way of showing the error markers in the editor? It doesn't need to be savable or anything... Just a way to tell the editor to create the same markers in the source code as if there were some `IMarker` attached to the opened `IResource`.

Comment: Assuming this a text editor based on the standard TextEditor I think you need to replace the Annotation Model to use something other than ResourceMarkerAnnotationModel.

Comment: Uff that sounds like a lot of work... Isn't there some sort of default to switch to instead?

Comment: I don't think so. Editors which operate on things outside of the workspace are not common and don't have as much support.

Comment: Alright thanks! Do you happen to know where to "register" the new annotationModel? As far as I have found out it is more or less linked with the Document of an editor though I couldn't find a method like `setAnnotationModel`...

Comment: Sorry but I haven't looked at this in a long time. Note you can use `IFile.createLink` to create a link inside the workspace to external resources which might be another way to approach this.

Comment: Okay I'll have look at this then. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the thing was that I was actually looking for the creation of an `Annotation` in the `AnnotationModel` of the `DocumentProvider`. There it could be added via `addAnnotation`.

That approachs works fine. However I haven't found a list of available annotation types (as there are for Markers), so it's a little tricky to actually get the proper annotation...